# How to concat String, File Contents, and String in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, string, concatenation

I have a file which contains only one line

```
$> cat file.txt
apple,orange,cat,dog
```

I need to append two String to it and assign it to a variable, one in front and another in the end, so that it becomes:

```
var=key,apple,orange,cat,dog,ending
```

so that I can use the $var somewhere else...

May I know how could I do that in bash script? Or any linux command can do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

One way would be this:

```
var="key,$(<file.txt),ending"
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is:

```
var=$(echo -n 'key,' && cat file.txt | tr '\n' ',' && echo 'ending')
```

- `$(...)` gets the output string of the commands in `...`
- `echo -n` prints the following string without a trailing newline
- `cat` prints the file's contents and `tr '\n' ','` replaces the trailing newline with a comma
- `echo` prints the following string with newline (which is not really important)

Comment: It doesn't work... would you please advise if I've done something wrong? As the follow: var=$(echo -n 'KEY,' && cat header-cp-match-src-file.csv | tr '\n' ',' && echo 'ID_BB_COMPANY,BB_CONAME,ID_BB_PARENT_CO,LONG_PARENT_COMP_NAME,COMPANY_CORP_TICKER,AVG_SIM_SCORE')

Comment: How should I know if you are doing something wrong, if you do not even post the contents of `$var`. I suggest you first try with your sample file and specifications from your question and test, if this gives the desired result. Then try with your original data and strings.